# What is the recommended approach for loading a Java Keystore from memory in a SpringBoot application running in a Docker container?

Tags: java, docker, spring-boot

I am looking for a solution to load a Java Keystore dynamically from memory instead of from a file on disk. Can you suggest any libraries or best practices for this scenario in the context of Java, SpringBoot, and Docker?

Comment: Please don't repost your [closed and deleted question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/443705/what-is-the-best-practice-for-loading-java-keystore-from-memory-in-a-docker-cont).

Answer (score -2):

We can load a keystore in Java without storing it in a Docker volume by reading the keystore data as a byte array, and then using the KeyStore.load() method that accepts a byte array as an argument.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;

public class KeystoreLoader {
    public static KeyStore loadKeyStore(String contents, String password) throws KeyStoreException,
            IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException {
        new ByteArrayInputStream(contents.getBytes());
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(inputStream, password.toCharArray());
            return keyStore;
        }
    }
}
```

Here `contents` is jks file contents which is injected from environment variable during application startup.